# Ionic 5 Capacitor Youtube Video Player doesnt work - shows there is no youtube applications. Get Youtube App error

Tags: ionic-framework, youtube-api, media-player

We have strange behavior on some phones (Poco, Xiaomi, Samsung) - when user is trying to play Youtube videos (using @awesome-cordova-plugins/youtube-video-player/ngx) this message shows:
"Get Youtube App. This app wont`t run withouth the Youtube App, which is missing from your device"
and
"Ann error occured while initializing the YouTube player"

in polish:
"Pobierz aplikację YouTube"

[image: no-yt-app]
[image: no-yt-app]
[image]

Comment: Hi any solution found for this?